# Target multiple div ID in the same function/event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run a function to allows several divs, each with it's own unique ID, in the same call. I thought this would work:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.onmouseover = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleDivs("ed1", "ed2", "ed3");
};
//function to hide or show
function toggleDivs(s){
    //reset
    document.getElementById("ed1").classList.remove("shown");
    //show
    document.getElementById(s).classList.add("shown");
}
```

It kind of works, but only the first div in the array (ed1) appears. The other two and I'm sure any more if I added them to the overall array, would not.

I tried having a toggleDivs for each div to appear (3 in all in this case), but no luck. What would be the way to get these to all appear at once instead of just the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In toggleDivs you are only using the first parameter.
Use an array to send all:

```
toggleDivs([ "ed1", "ed2", "ed3" ]);
```

The document.getElementById(id) function only receives one id at a time, so you have to iterate like this:

```
s.forEach(id => document.getElementById(id).classList.add("displayed"))
```

Comment: That was it. Brackets made all the difference. Thank you.